# What is the mathematical description of a point torque (or point couple) singularity?

Tags: forces, torque, singularities, greens-functions, structural-beam

Suppose that a concentrated (point) force is exerted at the origin of a 3D dimensional space along the direction $\boldsymbol{e}$. Mathematically, this could be prescribed in terms of a delta Dirac function as $F \delta(\boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{e}$, wherein $F$ is a constant. I was wondering how would a point torque be mathematically described in terms of the delta Dirac function. Any hints are most welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be noted that $F \delta(\boldsymbol{r})$ is not the force, but is called the Force Density (dimensionaly as well as physically), simply because integrating this over the volume gives you the force.

Now, Torque is defined as $r \times F$ where $r$ is the distance from the axis of rotation to the point of application of force. Now to have $r$ you should clearly have a force acting at a specific point. Hence, the standard definition of torque itself is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing! Just replace your force $F$ by the desired torque $M$ to get a point moment.